# How to pass uploaded file content to HttpPostedFileBase type in controller using angular js

Tags: c#, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

i am developing an asp.net mvc4 application with angularjs. I want to provide an choose file option along with some form data. By referring some links i provided an choose file option but the problem now is i am not able to pass the uploaded file content to controller where i am trying to store the path of a file into database.

***Below is my .cshtml page...***

```
  <div ng-app="formapp">
      <div ng-controller="FormController">
           <form name="myform" ng-submit="submit(myform.$valid)" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <p class="bg-text">User Name</p>
                   <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" ng-      model="username" placeholder="Username" required />
                        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="(myform.username.$dirty || submitted) && myform.username.$error.required">UserName is required</span>
                   </div>
               </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <p class="bg-text">Choose file</p>
                 <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" name="file" />
                 </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
          </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

***Script part is as follows...***

```
<script>

var formapp = angular.module('formapp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload']);
formapp.controller('FormController', function ($scope, $http, $upload) {  

    $scope.selectedFile = [];
    $scope.uploadProgress = 0;


    $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        $scope.uploadProgress = 0;
        $scope.selectedFile = $files;
    };

    $scope.submit = function (isValid) {

          $scope.object = {              
              UserName: $scope.username,              
          };

          var file = $scope.selectedFile[0];

          var request = $http({
                  method: "post",
                  url: "/Admin/SaveUser",
                  data: $scope.object,
                  file:file
              }).success(function (data) {
                  if (data.success)
                      window.location.href = data.Url;
                  else {
                      alert(data.message);
                      $scope.username = "";
                      $scope.EmployeeDetailId = "";
                  }
              }).error(function (data) {
                        window.location.href = data.Url;
                    });
          }
      }
});
</script>
```

***Below is my controller...***

```
public ActionResult SaveUser(RegisteredUser data, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
      string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Pictures/" + ImageName);
      data.picture = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(physicalPath);
      db.RegisteredUsers.Add(data);
      db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

**Problem:**

HttpPostedFileBase always returning null at controller but when i debug the cshtml page i able to see that the 'file' parameter holds all the content of uploaded data.

[image]

where i am making mistake, Please help me to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous to HTML5, there was no way to send a file over AJAX. With HTML5, if you want to do this, you must first use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to read the file data, and then put the content of the file into your POST object manually. You still can't just serialize the form and call it day. Also, since this is HTML5 only, the usual caveats apply. It won't work in anything but modern browsers, which is IE10+, for example. If you need to still support IE7 or IE8, then you can't do it this way. You'll instead need to make use of some Flash or Java component for file uploads. There's tons of different libraries; just do a search.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, now to upload file instead of making ajax request i am using "angulafileupload" and made request like below                     $upload.upload({method: "post",url: "/Admin/SaveUser",                data: $scope.object,file: file,async:true});